# How to make an exception for a template not to load on AMP in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, templates, amp-html, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I have my web page full on AMP using too the oficial plugin. I use templates for my content, the template is used everytime someone makes a post. All the page is in AMP but if I want that just one template just do not load in AMP, how can I make that happen? I tried using functions.php with no success

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `amp_is_request` in your template.

```
if ( function_exists( 'amp_is_request' ) && amp_is_request() ) {
   /* AMP Request */
} else {
   /* non AMP Request */
}
```

Otherwise you can use `amp_skip_post` filter in your functions.php:

```
add_action(
    'wp',
    function() {
        $template_slug = get_page_template_slug($post_id);
        if ( $template_slug == 'Your template slug' ) {
            add_filter( 'amp_skip_post', '__return_true' );
        }
    }
);
```

Note that both solutions will load full page in non AMP mode. If you want to load one of components in non AMP you can try using [Sanitizers](https://amp-wp.org/documentation/playbooks/sanitizers/) but still, that page is going to be AMP.